# Easy to implement way to store images on database?

Tags: android

I'm working on a project which requires users, and image uploads/downloads. The user side of the backend I'm using Firebase, which was very straight forward to implement. I'm now realizing that I probably shouldn't be storing the image/byte[] itself on a Firebase server, I should probably store the image to the cloud and make a reference to it in the database, right?

If that's the case, I'm not sure which service to use that would be straight forward to use. I just need to upload an image. Looked into Google Cloud Storage, but their docs weren't all that great and I couldn't find many resources for Android.

Any recommended services for a novice in this field?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should definitely store the image as image not blob or byte array.

If you look for integration to Android, some other services other than Google Cloud Storage that have their SDK for Android would be AWS S3 and Azure. I use Google Cloud Engine and AWS S3 but I don't use Azure so I can't speak for it. When the two are compared, S3 offers more regional endpoints across the world which probably helps in term of latency whereas Google is a bit cheaper, at least for the time being. Also S3 having been around longer probably has more resources and [users](https://www.datanyze.com/market-share/cdn/amazon-s3-vs-google-cloud-storage/). If you don't like [official tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/s3transfermanager.html) you can use full ready to deploy [project examples](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/S3_TransferManager) which they regularly release.

Comment: I'm not doubting you, just curious. Why is it better to store the actual image vs the byte array? I just thought the process of creating an image of the correct size would be easier if the byte array was passed between clients instead of the image itself.

Comment: Actually we don't pass the file but the url. And by client I suppose you are referring to a UI element or View loading the image. In Android image loading framework is similar to browser's where two img elements (here ImageView) loading a same image (having a same url) don't download it twice or pass it between them but share a single image in the cache.